# Extracting url path using regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

**Scenario**

I want to extract the path string from the document.location, excluding the leading slash.
So for example, if the url is:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```

I would get:

```
questions/ask
```

This should be straightforward:

```
/* group everything after the leading slash */
var re = /\/(.+)/gi;
var matches = document.location.pathname.match(re);
console.log(matches[0]);
```

But if I run this snippet in the firebug console, I still get the leading slash.
I have already tested the [regexp](http://regexr.com/3a11g), and the regexp engine correctly extract the group.

**Question**

How to properly get the group 1 string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying trailing or leading slash? From your post it looks like leading slash.

```
document.location.pathname.replace(/^\//,"")
```

By the way, your regexp is right, but you just need to remove `gi` and read `matches[1]` rather than `matches[0]`, because `matches[0]` is the whole string matches the regexp, while `matches[1]` is the captured part within the matched string (quote with brackets in the regexp).

```
var matches = document.location.pathname.match(/\/(.+)/);
console.log(matches); // ["/questions/ask", "questions/ask"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need regular expressions if you just want to get pathname without leading slash. Since `location.pathname` always starts with `/` you can simply take the substring from the first index:

```
document.location.pathname.substr(1) // or .slice(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regex you can do:

```
var m = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask'.match(/\/{2}[^\/]+(\/.+)/);
console.log(m[1]); /questions/ask
```